# Enable BFQ in Fedora

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am running Fedora with the stock kernel and I'd like to enable the BFQ disk I/O scheduler, and ideally BFS.  I have built my own kernel and that works, though it is a royal pain dealing with the Nvidia drivers.

Can I enable BFQ and BFS without building my own kernel, such as by adding kernel args to grub?  If not, is there a kernel package available that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `bfq` or `bfs` patches applied to the Fedora kernels unfortunately (esp. in the case of `bfq`). So there is no way to enable those features by adding kernel args. Further, there is no trusted Fedora repository that has kernels with those features enabled. It seems that until `bfq` becomes part of mainline you will have to keep creating the kernels yourself.

Comment: I found this blog post that it worked from Fedora 21, and it works up to Fedora 25 - http://www.hecticgeek.com/2015/10/make-gnu-linux-responsive/

Answer (score 1):

BFQ is now merged in Linux kernel 4.12, as a blk-mq scheduler.  For example, this means that you can enable it with a SATA disk on current kernels (4.12-4.20), provided that you boot with scsi-mq enabled.  (Current planning for 4.21 is that blk-mq will become the only option).

All the steps required to use blk-mq and BFQ on SATA/SCSI disks are documented in this answer:

[How to enable and use the BFQ scheduler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-enable-and-use-the-bfq-scheduler/376136#376136)