# How to enable and use the BFQ scheduler?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I just installed Linux kernel version 4.12 on Ubuntu 17.04 using ukuu (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/ubuntu_kernel_upgrade_utility).

The thing is, when I check the available I/O schedulers, I can't seem to find the BFQ nor the Kyber I/O scheduler :

```
cat /sys/class/block/sda/queue/scheduler
> noop deadline [cfq]
```

So how to use one of the new schedulers in this Linux version ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not in Ubuntu, but what I did in Fedora may help you.

BFQ is a blk-mq (Multi-Queue Block IO Queueing Mechanism) scheduler, so you need to enable blk-mq at boot time, edit your /etc/default/grub file and add `scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1` to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, this is my grub file, as an example:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=false
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet vt.global_cursor_default=0 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

After that, you must update your grub.  On Fedora we have to use `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /path/to/grub.cfg`, which varies [depending on the boot method](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f29/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/index.html#sec-Editing_a_Menu_Entry).  On Ubuntu, you can simply run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot, and if you get this:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
```

Probably your kernel was compiled with **BFQ as a module**, and this can be the case also for Kyber.

```
sudo modprobe bfq
sudo cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] bfq none
```

You can add it at boot time by adding a `/etc/modules-load.d/bfq.conf` file containing `bfq`.

**It is important to note that enabling blk_mq turn it impossible to use non blk_mq schedulers, so you will lose noop cfq and the non mq deadline**

Apparently blk_mq scheduling system is not supporting elevator flags in grub, udev rules can be used instead, with a bonus of offering a more grained control.

Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-scheduler.rules` if it did not exist and add:

```
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"
```

As pointed [here](https://gist.github.com/wooptoo/835f377d88ef9fb11a21e735630d7470) if needed you can distinguish between rotational (HDDs) and non-rotational (SSDs) devices in udev rules using the attribute `ATTR{queue/rotational}`. Be aware that Paolo Valente, BFQ developer, pointed in LinuxCon Europe that BFQ can be a better choice than the `noop` or `deadline` schedulers in terms of low latency guaranties, what makes a good advice to use it for SSDs too.

Paolo's comparison: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cjZeaCXIyM&feature=youtu.be

Save it, and reload and trigger `udev rules`:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
sudo udevadm trigger
```

Comment: I just want to note: don't do this on computers with Linux < 4.15 that you expect to be able to suspend-to-ram; < 4.15 will hang all IO on resume because they lack the "safe SCSI quiescing" fixes.

Comment: You may also have problems on kernel 4.14 where enabling blk-mq seems to give a kernel "oops" right at the beginning of loading the kernel on some systems (it's not a full stop panic, just a null dereference inside the kernel). You might miss it if you're not looking for it but if you're paranoid it could be a sign that something is broken.

Comment: I'd suggest using a slightly more accurate udev rule. When I tried the one shown here, udev tried to set the scheduler for some devices whose names match that pattern, but aren't SCSI block devices that can use the BFQ scheduler. The rule I ended up with is this:
`ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DRIVERS=="sd|sr", ATTR{queue/scheduler}!="bfq", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"`
It avoids pattern matching against names of devices, which makes the matching more accurate. It won't match partition devices because they don't have the "queue/scheduler" attribute.

Comment: Also important to note is that kernels 4.15-4.16 suffer from a pretty severe bug where updating the partition scheme of a drive while using BFQ can lead to a complete I/O lock-up. Cf.: https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/12/1/80

Comment: You can also `echo bfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler` as root. (sudo did not work for me in Ubuntu 18.04) This should make it effective immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To extend great [RomuloPBenedetti answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/376136/338576):

You can test, if bfq scheduler is actually available on particular device by using `PROGRAM=="/bin/grep -E -q '(^|[[:space:]])bfq($|[[:space:]])' '$sys$devpath/queue/scheduler'"` in udev rule. This will effectually replace `DRIVERS=="sd|sr"` and just not fire if one forgot `scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1`

Trivia:

- `PROGRAM` - Execute a program to determine whether there is a match; the key is true if the program returns successfully; If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in /lib/udev.
- `$sys` - The sysfs mount point (`/sys`).
- `$devpath` - The devpath of the device (/devices/pci/...).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share with the community of my successful implementation of the recommendations made above by **RomuloPBenedetti**.

I needed to do this because when I used the command

```
nice -n 17 tar cf - . | ( cd ${there} ; nice -n 17 tar xvpf - )
```

for a partition (/DB001_F5 on root device) to partition (/site/DB002_F5 on separate device) **mirroring of 250 GB**, **my system was not usable**. I was under the impression that the nice command should have taken care of that ... but it did not!

**After implementation**, I have very minor delay (1/2 - 1 sec) when switching applications or workspaces or cursor interactions.

**Before implementation**, the delays were, *without joking*, of the order of minutes! I was unable to get the immediate response for the mouse or scrolling button, that is needed to even think it was interactive, rather than a "snail-mail" interaction.

Also of note, the transfer before the "tweaks" took about 90 minutes.  Afterwards, it took only 48:

```
29.23user 
902.53system 
47:39.63elapsed 
32%CPU 
(0avgtext+0avgdata 3160maxresident)k
```

For those who might ask, I had tried the low-latency version of my kernel, but that did not offer the benefit of improved interactive response priority.

**My Desktop Configuration**
My desktop is **UbuntuMATE 20.04 LTS**.

```
Linux {myhost} 5.4.0-94-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP 
Thu Jan 6 23:58:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
4 GB RAM
Only HDDs
```