# Can't run any snap using linux 4.12 : snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 with linux kernel `4.12.2` which I installed using the software `ukuu` (Ubuntu Update Kernel Utility).

Every time I try to run a snap in my system when I am using this linux kernel version, I get this error (for example the `hello-world` snap) :

```
/snap/bin/hello-world
>snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

I tried going back to kernel version `4.10.0-28-generic` and the snaps are working just fine over there.

So can any one tell me what's the problem, and how to solve it ?

## Additional informations

I don't know if this is important or not, but I used this answer [How to use BFQ scheduler on Linux 4.12?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-use-bfq-scheduler-on-linux-4-12/376136?noredirect=1#comment670482_376136) to activate and use `bfq` scheduler on linux kernel `4.12.2`.

## Update

This is really weird. When I went back to kernel version `4.12.2` after using the snaps in the kernel version `4.10.0-28-generic` ; snaps now are working again in `4.12.2`.

## Update

The snaps are working, but not they are having some bugs. Sometimes the 
confinement doesn't work, and the snap can access anything.

Comment: created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1732409