# How to enable Kyber scheduler in Ubuntu 17.10 kernel 4.13?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, block-device, nvme

I was wondering how to enable Kyber scheduler in Ubuntu 17.10, which has kernel 4.13 by default. I got bfq enabled using the instructions from [How to enable and use the BFQ scheduler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-enable-and-use-the-bfq-scheduler). When I navigate to my NVMe drive, I am seeing only bfq.

```
cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler
[noop] bfq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily enable the three available schedulers via:

- sudo modprobe bfq
- sudo modprobe mq-deadline
- sudo modprobe kyber-iosched

You can see the available modules in `/lib/modules/<your kernel>/kernel/block`.

To enable these modules on boot, you can add the following lines to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf` (or by creating another .conf in the same directory):

```
bfq
mq-deadline
kyber-iosched
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fedora 28 and kernel 4.17 but I think it works the same way.

Just set it to "kyber" and it'll autoload the kyber-iosched module.

Some people use scripts and such but I like udev rules. Here's mine from `/etc/udev/rules.d/iosched.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="nvme?n?", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="kyber", ATTR{queue/io_poll_delay}="0"
```

I'm still experimenting with that `io_poll_delay`, you don't need it for anything.