# How to disable blk-mq for NVMe and use CFQ, deadline, noop?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

For testing purposes, I would like to use `CFQ`, `deadline`, and `noop` for an NVMe drive. Is this possible?

I am able to use the blk-mq for SATA SSDs by adding `"scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1"` to the grub boot (see: [How to enable and use the BFQ scheduler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-enable-and-use-the-bfq-scheduler)).

But have yet to find a way to do the reverse for NVMe drives to allow them to use the non blk-mq schedulers.

Comment: Please accept the answer below. It is useful and answers your question.

Comment: I have removed the incorrect claim from the answer that blk-mq does not use schedulers - and pointed out that this was how it *used* to work.  Nevertheless, to the best of my knowledge the answer is "no, you can't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev/sda  <-- SCSI device
/dev/nvme0n1 <-- NVMe device

NVMe driver supported blk-mq since kernel version 3.19.  It didn't allow  turning off blk-mq by using an insmod parameter, or a kernel boot option in grub.

```
$ modinfo -p nvme
use_threaded_interrupts: (int)
use_cmb_sqes:use controller's memory buffer for I/O SQes (bool)
max_host_mem_size_mb:Maximum Host Memory Buffer (HMB) size per controller (in MiB) (uint)
sgl_threshold:Use SGLs when average request segment size is larger or equal to this size. Use 0 to disable SGLs. (uint)
io_queue_depth:set io queue depth, should >= 2
```

You could download old nvme driver and recompile kernel module from http://git.infradead.org/users/willy/linux-nvme.git if you want to disable blk-mq.  However, this did *not* allow using e.g. CFQ.  The [relevant change in 3.19](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a4aea5623d4a54682b6ff5c18196d7802f3e478f) explains that the NVMe driver previously "[implemented] queue logic within itself", it did not use the single-queue block layer.  There are other examples of such block devices, for example Linux `mdraid` devices.

---

The following sources were correct at the time, they include some useful notes and links.  They are however out of date, as they were written before the introduction of blk-mq IO schedulers, including BFQ (BFQ was accepted as part of Linux 4.12).

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Multi-Queue_Block_IO_Queueing_Mechanism_(blk-mq)

Linux Storage Diagram from https://www.thomas-krenn.com.
  https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wikiDE/images/d/da/Linux-io-stack-diagram_v1.0.png